# Failed to deploy zend application on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: zend-framework, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need help for deploy my aplication into Elastic Beanstalk.
So far, I only want deploy the sample provided by Zend, without BD, services, etc. (base squeleton aplication).

I have followed these steps:

- Enter into Elastic Beanstalk console (without application).
- Create a PHP 5.4 enviroment.
- Change in (Edit/Load Configuration -> Container Tab): Document Root= \public
- Clicked "Upload New Version" and configure for deploy to existing enviroment (Default).

Important:

- The File uploaded is a .Zip File of the base skeleton path.
- My project has been developed under Windows and use xampp with PHP Version 5.4.7.
- I used Eclipse for develop, I don't have Zend Studio.

After uploading, a event error is showed (Failed to deploy application version).

What am I being wrong? or what steps missing for do it well?

Answer (score 0):

I put zend folder on LIBRARY inside project

> /projectfolder/library/

works for me